# Can't download a PDF generated with TCPDF using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

I want to get a PDF of an HTML file, I am using TCPDF to generate the PDF and AJAX to send the information. Right now, I am only trying to get a PDF of one SVG on the page, when I get this done I will do the rest.

The problem is that TCPDF generates the PDF but instead of downloading it, it passes it to the javascript cosole. When I don't use AJAX it works perfect.

Here is the AJAX code:

```
// Get the d3js SVG element
var tmp  = document.getElementById("elemPD5graf");
var svg = tmp.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

// Extract the data as SVG text string
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);  

var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var parameters = { datos : svg_xml };
j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'generarPDF.php',
    data : parameters,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('..\tcpdf\tcpdf.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 058', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// NOTE: Uncomment the following line to rasterize SVG image using the ImageMagick library.
//$pdf->setRasterizeVectorImages(true);
$svg2 = $_POST['datos'];

$pdf->ImageSVG($file='@'.$svg2, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('nuevo.pdf', 'D');
//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
?>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried saving the pdf and returning the URL of the saved file, instead of returning the content of the pdf?

Comment: @Timothy With the 'Output' method on the PHP code it is suposed to save the PDF. It works when I don't use AJAX.

Comment: You are using the output method `'D'`, this will send the document to your browser and start a download. This wont work when you receive it through an AJAX call.

Comment: @Timothy and which should I use? it shoud work with 'F', right?

Comment: If you really want to use AJAX , the only way is to save the document on your server and return the pdf url `echo $pdf->Output('/path/to/pdf/nuevo.pdf', 'F');`

Comment: I only use AJAX because is the solution I found to pass a lot of information from JavaScript to PHP.  It doesn't work the solution you have said, I get this error: `Unable to create output file:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$returnValue = $pdf->Output($name, $destination);
```

$destination can take one of the following values:

> I: send the file inline to the browser (default). The name given by
>   name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link
>   generating the PDF.
>
> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given
>   by name.
>
> F: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
>
> S: return the document as a string (name is ignored).
>
> FI: equivalent to F + I option
>
> FD: equivalent to F + D option
>
> E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC
>   2045)

The error `Unable to create output file` means that TCPDF can't write your document to your folder. Provide a valid path in `$name`.

Comment: @timothy the documentation link you provided doesn't work anymore. Can you please provide an alternative

Comment: @Annapurna https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Output. I can't seem to find an updated URL which would provide additional information other than the info I already have in this answer. I'll remove the URL from my answer

Answer (score 0):

The pdf is printed to the Javascript console due to your line

```
console.log(result);
```

Possible solutions:

- Save the pdf in a temporary file on the server and return a URL to this file which you then assign to `location.href`.
- Don't use Ajax, but instead a `<form>`.
- You could try `document.write(result)`

Comment: If I try to use a form, I get an error that says that the URL is too long.

Comment: maybe try using `method="POST"` instead of `GET`, in your form

Comment: This is crucial due to the fact that you use `$_POST` in your php script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when tried to download PDF in POST call,
try to call you generarPDF.php page directly (with GET) and will work corrcetly.